# Custom Post Types not showing on Custom Taxonomy archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've been working with custom post types for a little while now, but yesterday I took my first stab at a custom taxonomy to pair with them.

Here is my 'company' taxonomy:

```
function create_company_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Companies', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Company', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Companies' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Companies' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Company' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Company:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Companies' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Companies' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Company' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Company Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Company' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'company' ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'company', array( 'brochures','business-cards','post','websites' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_company_taxonomy', 0 );
```

As you can see I am trying to use it with 'posts' as well as three custom post types--'brochures','business-cards','websites'

When I create a taxonomy-company.php template (based off archive.php) and give each of these post_types a term from the taxonomy, only posts display on the page. I cannot get the custom post types to display at all.

Do I need a custom query? Any insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is one of my register_post_types as well

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_post_types' );
function create_custom_post_types() {

   $labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Websites' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Website' )
    );

    $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'websites'),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category','company','post_tag' ),
    'supports'  => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' , 'custom-fields', 'excerpt' ),
    'exclude_from_search' => true
    );

  register_post_type( 'websites', $args);
}
```

Comment: `exclude_from_search` should be `false`. Reflush your permalinks afterwards

Comment: @Pieter Goosen: Man, you are good! Thanks, that worked. I had that in there because have a search box on my blog page and only want the default post types to be included in search. I'll have to figure out another way to set it up, but at least my custom tax now works!

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to remove your post types from the search query ;-)

Comment: @Pieter Goosen: Yes, looking at my functions.php now and it appears that I did that as well. So I should be good to go. I'm still a bit of a noob on here, but if there is a way I can upvote you I would. You rock!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all public post types are included in the main main query on taxonomy pages. If you look at `register_post_type()'s`public parameter when set to true

> - **'true'**
> - Implies `exclude_from_search`: false, `publicly_queryable`: true, `show_in_nav_menus`: true, and `show_ui`:true.

When you register your post type, you set `exclude_from_search` to `true`. This does not only remove the custom post type from search, but also from the main query on the taxonomy page. Again, from the codex for the `exclude_from_search` parameter

> Note: If you want to show the posts's list that are associated to taxonomy's terms, you must set exclude_from_search to false (ie : for call `site_domaine/?taxonomy_slug=term_slug` or `site_domaine/taxonomy_slug/term_slug`). If you set to true, on the taxonomy page (ex: `taxonomy.php`) WordPress will not find your posts and/or pagination will make 404 error.

### SOLUTION

You need to set `exclude_from_search` to false, reflush your permalinks and your good to go. If you need to exclude a post type from the search page, you can use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to remove the post type from the main query

### EDIT

Just for interest sake, here is the piece of code in the `WP_Query` class (*in wp-includes/query.php*) which is responsible to include and exclude post types from the main query on taxonomy term archive pages

```
if ( $this->is_tax ) {
    if ( empty($post_type) ) {
        // Do a fully inclusive search for currently registered post types of queried taxonomies
        $post_type = array();
        $taxonomies = array_keys( $this->tax_query->queried_terms );
        foreach ( get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false ) ) as $pt ) {
            $object_taxonomies = $pt === 'attachment' ? get_taxonomies_for_attachments() : get_object_taxonomies( $pt );
            if ( array_intersect( $taxonomies, $object_taxonomies ) )
                $post_type[] = $pt;
        }
        if ( ! $post_type )
            $post_type = 'any';
        elseif ( count( $post_type ) == 1 )
            $post_type = $post_type[0];

        $post_status_join = true;
    } elseif ( in_array('attachment', (array) $post_type) ) {
        $post_status_join = true;
    }
}
```

The important part here is: `get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false )`. It is here where the query gets all public post types where `exclude_from_search` is set to `false`. All post types therefor with `exclude_from_search` set to `true` will be excluded from the query, and that is why your custom post types does not get included in the taxonomy term archive page

Comment: Gotcha. Accepted this answer and I am moving ahead with my site changes. Thanks again.

Comment: awesome, thank you good sir! I had exclude from search set to true and lost like 5hours to make the archive page show the taxonomy posts